# Парсинг сайта BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу получить все криптовалюты с сайта https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/ с помощью request. Так как там сайт выдает 200 валют, а дальше идет кнопка Load More. Как парсить такие страницы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суп не нужен.

Сайт отдает данные по АПИ

```
https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?convert=USD,BTC,ETH,XRP,BCH,LTC&cryptocurrency_type=all&limit=200&sort=market_cap&sort_dir=desc&start=201
```

Просто меняй цифры 
`limit=200`
`start=0`, потом start=201 и пока не получишь строк меньше лимита

Comment: этот запрос не получит все валюты

Comment: Просто меняй цифры limit=200 start=0 и получай валюты дальне